# Why does calling chrome.cast.initialize break the connection to the Chromecast device?

Tags: chromecast

I am trying to build a custom Chromecast sender/receiver application, but I can't seem to connect to the device from my custom sender or even Chrome once my custom sender page is loaded.

The Chromecast device appears to be functioning properly (I can cast tabs and YouTube videos). However, when I load the custom sender, it seems to break Chromes connection to the device. The Chromecast icon in Chrome shows "No Cast devices found".

I have found if I comment out `chrome.cast.initialize`, I can see the Chromecast device again. There are no errors reported in the Chrome debug console and I've commented out all of my code that is called from event handlers related to that call and I still have the same problem. I've also tried resetting the Chromecast device to factory. I've tried a few of the network tweaks recommended in a few other posts as well (though I get the impression they couldn't connect to the device at all).

This was working perfectly yesterday, then it mysteriously stopped. That seems to point to something I might have done, but the only thing I changed was in the receiver app and since I can't get that to start, I don't think it is that.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error before and I solved it by closing then re-openning the Chrome browser. If you are sure 100% that your js code works as expected when calling chrome.cast.initialize (no error show in Console mode but you got no ChromeCast extension found error), then simply close your Chrome browser and re-open it. If in your console, after calling chrome.cast.initialize, you see the line ChromeCast extension found :.... then you should be able to see your ChromeCast device when clicking into ChromeCast extension icon. If re-open browser does not work, clear your browser cache and try again.

Hope it helps.